# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTIONS | SWIFT

Tags: swift, multithreading, random

When i am starting the app, it runs normal. When i click randomize button, **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTIONS** comes at `finalLABEL.text = str` point.
**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

```
@IBOutlet var fromACT: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var toEXT: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var finalLABEL: UILabel!
func unsafeRandomIntFrom(start: Int32, to end: Int32) -> Int32 {
    let number =  Int32(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(end - start + 1))) + start
    return number
}

@IBAction func random(sender: AnyObject) {
    let convertedNumber = NSString(string: fromACT.text!).intValue
    let convertedNumber2 = NSString(string: toEXT.text!).intValue
    let randomSV = unsafeRandomIntFrom(convertedNumber, to: convertedNumber2)
    let str = String(randomSV)

    finalLABEL.text? = str
}
```

Comment: You syntax in the last line is wrong. It's supposed to say `finalLabel?.text = str`, or just `finalLabel.text = str`.

Comment: @David 
I've corrected it to finalLabel.text = str, but there is still same problem

Comment: Add a breakpoint in your unsafeRandomIntFrom and another in your random function. Go step by step and tell us where it fails

Comment: @H4Hugo it fails at the last line

Comment: I'm almost certain that `finalLABEL` is simply nil. Probably a bad outlet connection, or you're calling the function before `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: @David Thank you really much, i've just accidentally deleted **finalLABEL** outlet. now it's reconnected and works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to protect your code :

```
...
let convertedNumber = NSString(string: fromACT.text!).intValue
let convertedNumber2 = NSString(string: toEXT.text!).intValue
let randomSV = unsafeRandomIntFrom(convertedNumber, to: convertedNumber2)
if Int(randomSV) != nil {
    let str = String(randomSV)
    finalLABEL.text? = str
}
```

You could set also a default values to your function:

```
func unsafeRandomIntFrom(start: Int32 = 3, to end: Int32 = 6) -> Int32 {
    let number =  Int32(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(end - start + 1))) + start
    return number
}
```

to ensure whenever you want to call your function without values, to have a default values.

Comment: I used a protection one, it worked. but the error still appearing. It means, that **str** is not empty, but **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** is still showing

Comment: First of all welcome to Stack Overflow, what happened now?

Comment: if let r = randomSV { **initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not in32**

Comment: Oh yes right, because its valorized as Int32, try now

Comment: **Value of type int32 can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed** now appears

Comment: Converted to Int it would be ok also for Swift 2.2